# Additional space at end of page on tablet/mobile version

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-5

I have to design a web-shop for university and I am having troubles and I cannot find the problem. On certain pages when I look at the tablet or mobile version there is so much space after the HTML tag. I cannot find the mistake. Also this only happens on half of the pages, not on every page.

I have tried to comment out a few lines in CSS (body - `min-height` and `content`), that does nothing. I've also checked if I forgot to close a tag somewhere. Nothings seems to work and I am desperate, please help.

```css
* {
  font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", Calibri, "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
  color: cornsilk;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.registrierungLabel {
  color: rgba(126, 79, 24, 0.514);
}

a {
  color: rgb(184, 107, 82);
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: cornsilk;
}

html {
  overflow: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0;
  /* Remove scrollbar space */
  background: transparent;
  /* Optional: just make scrollbar invisible */
}

body {
  padding-top: 140px;
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
  min-height: auto;
  background-color: #e9aa83;
}

.btn {
  border-style: none;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.btn-primary {
  background-color: cornsilk;
  color: rgb(184, 107, 82);
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: rgb(184, 107, 82);
  color: cornsilk !important;
}

.accordion-item {
  border-color: rgba(135, 74, 54, 0.79);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .card-image {
    width: 300px;
  }
  .card-products {
    width: 300px;
  }
}

.card-products {
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
}

.content {
  min-height: calc(100% - 50px);
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: #e9aa83;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>guapo. | Hilfe</title>

  <link rel="icon" href="images/clementine.png" sizes="16x16 32x32" type="image/png" />
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.3/font/bootstrap-icons.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css" />
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.js" integrity="sha256-nQLuAZGRRcILA+6dMBOvcRh5Pe310sBpanc6+QBmyVM=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="navbar"></div>


  <div class="container content">
    <p>
      Durch Klick auf gewünschten Tab gelangst du zur gewünschten Seite.
      <br /> Bei Fragen und Anregungen wende dich bitte an uns: <a href="mailto:ww22e019@technikum-wien.at">
        ww22e019@technikum-wien.at
      </a>
    </p>

    <h2>FAQs</h2>

    <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">

      <div class="accordion-item">
        <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
          <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne" style="background-color: rgba(194, 116, 79, 0.877); color: cornsilk;">
            Wie lange dauert die Lieferung meiner Bestellung?
          </button>
        </h2>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
          <div class="accordion-body" style="background-color: rgba(194, 115, 79, 0.721);">
            Wir versenden aus Österreich nach ganz Europa. In der Regel dauert dies 3-5 Werktage.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="accordion-item">
        <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingTwo">
          <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo" style="background-color: rgba(194, 116, 79, 0.877); color: cornsilk;">
            Kann ich meine Bestellung zurücksenden oder umtauschen?
          </button>
        </h2>
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
          <div class="accordion-body" style="background-color: rgba(194, 115, 79, 0.721);">
            Ja, du kannst deine Bestellung innerhalb von 14 Tagen nach Erhalt zurücksenden oder umtauschen. Bitte beachte, dass die Artikel ungetragen und in ihrem ursprünglichen Zustand sein müssen.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="accordion-item">
        <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingThree">
          <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree" style="background-color: rgba(194, 116, 79, 0.877); color: cornsilk;">
            Welche Zahlungsmethoden akzeptiert der Shop?
          </button>
        </h2>
        <div id="collapseThree" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
          <div class="accordion-body" style="background-color: rgba(194, 115, 79, 0.721);">
            Wir akzeptieren Kreditkarten, PayPal, Sofortüberweisung und Vorkasse.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="accordion-item">
        <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingFour">
          <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseFour" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseFour" style="background-color: rgba(194, 116, 79, 0.877); color: cornsilk;">
            Wie pflege ich die Kleidungsstücke richtig?
          </button>
        </h2>
        <div id="collapseFour" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingFour" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
          <div class="accordion-body" style="background-color: rgba(194, 115, 79, 0.721);">
            Die Pflegeanweisungen findest du auf dem Etikett jedes Artikels. Bitte beachte, dass manche Artikel professionell gereinigt werden sollten oder auf niedriger Temperatur gewaschen werden müssen.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="footer"></div>

  <script src="./javascript/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I think you have provided padding-top:140px in body that's why maybe you are seeing too much space in the top. you can try percentages like padding-top:10% or something;

Comment: @himanshu no, the extra space I get is at the end, after the footer. And if I inspect the page it shows that my html tag ends directly after the footer and then there just a lot of space with nothing down from there.

Comment: What do you expect to see when the content is less than then viewport's height?

Comment: @DarkBee yeah, but it also happens to pages where there is enough content.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You forgot to give the body the height. Just simply give it height: 100vh and it will work fine. I'm hoping that is the problem if not let me know and we can work out a different solution

Comment: Yes, that's it, I've figured it out yesterday, always thought you should not give 100vh to your body but thank you so much!